# Suggestions for improvement of HTML table building function

Tags: php, html, php5

**User specification**

- "`var_dump($GLOBALS)` is ugly as `...` without wamp"

**General specification**

- Produce a PHP function to display the contents of `$GLOABLS` in a user-friendly manner
- Must produce properly indented HTML
- Must include appropriate CSS classes for customisability

So far, this is what I've got:

```
function __printRow($key, $value, $row)
{
    $type = gettype($value);
    $typeAndValue = __valueAndString($type, $value);
    $typeLabel = $typeAndValue['type'];
    $value = $typeAndValue['value'];
    echo _tab(5) . "<tr class=\"_v_row_alt_" . $row % 2 . "\">\n" .
             _tab(6) . "<td class=\"_v_key\">$key</td>\n" .
             _tab(6) . "<td class=\"_v_type _v_typelabel_$type\">$typeLabel</td>\n" .
             _tab(6) . "<td class=\"_v_value _v_type_$type\">$value</td>\n" .
         _tab(5) . "</tr>\n";
}//End __printRow()

function _tab($num)
{
    $tabs = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        $tabs .= "\t";
    }//End for
    return $tabs;
}//End _tab()

function __valueAndString($type, $value)
{
    $return = ['type' => $type, 'value' => $value];
    if($value === null)
    {
        $return['type'] = $return['value'] = 'null';
        return $return;
    }//End if
    switch($type)
    {
        case 'array':
            $return['value'] = '[';
            $count = count($value);
            $return['type'] = "$type <font class=\"_v_length\">($count)</font>";
            for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
            {
                $subType = $value[$i] === null ? 'null' : gettype($value[$i]);
                $subTypesAndValues = __valueAndString($subType, $value[$i]);
                $subValue = $subTypesAndValues['value'];
                $return['value'] .= "<font class=\"_v_type_$subType\">$subValue</font>";
                if(($i + 1) < $count)
                {
                    $return['value'] .= ', ';
                }//End if
            }//End for
            $return['value'] .= ']';
            break;

        case 'boolean':
            $return['value'] = $value ? 'true' : 'false';
            break;

        case 'string':
            $return['type'] = "$type <span class=\"_v_length\">(" . strlen($value) . ')</span>';
            $return['value'] = "'$value'";
            break;
    }//End switch
    return $return;
}//End __valueAndString()

function ___v()
{
    $globals = $GLOBALS;
    unset($globals['GLOBALS']); //Remove reference to $GLOBALS
    if(!isset($globals['_SERVER']))
    {
        //Didn't appear when run on a VM, not 100% sure that's why
        $globals['_SERVER'] = $_SERVER;
    }
    ksort($globals);
    echo "\n" . _tab(2) . "<div class=\"_v_container\">\n";
    if(empty($_SESSION))
    {
        echo _tab(2) . "<div class=\"_v _v_info\"><span class=\"_v_info_var_name\">" .
             "Session</span> is " . (!isset($_SESSION) ? 'not set' : 'empty') . ".</div><br />\n";
    }//End if
    foreach($globals as $varName => $super)
    {
        if(!is_array($super))
        {
            __printRow($varName, $super, 0);
        }//End if
        elseif(!empty($super))
        {
            ksort($super);
            $varName = ucfirst(strtolower(substr($varName, 1)));
            echo _tab(3) . "<div class=\"_v_table\">\n" .
                 _tab(4) . "<span class=\"_v _v_title\" id=\"_v_$varName" . "_title\">$varName</span>\n" .
                    _tab(5) . "<table class=\"_v _v_properties\" id=\"_v$varName\">\n";
            $row = 0;
            foreach($super as $key => $value)
            {
                __printRow($key, $value, $row++);
            }//End foreach
            echo    _tab(4) . "</table>\n" .
                 _tab(3) . "</div>\n";
        }//End if
    }//End foreach
    echo _tab(2) . "</div>\n";
}//End __v()
```

Which I've been testing using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
            ._v { font-family: 'Tw Cen MT', serif; }

            ._v_container { clear: both; }

            ._v_key { text-align: right; }

            ._v_length { font-style: italic; }

            ._v_properties { column-width: auto; }

            ._v_row_alt_0 { background-color: rgba(99, 184, 230, 0.15); }

            ._v_table { float: left; }

            ._v_title, ._v_info_var_name { font-weight: bold; }

            ._v_type
            {
                width: 1px;
                white-space: nowrap;
                color: #575757;
                text-align: center;
            }

            ._v_type_boolean, ._v_type_null { color: #0000E6; }

            ._v_type_double { color: #f57900; }

            ._v_type_integer { color: #4e9a06; }

            ._v_type_string { color: #cc0000; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        /* include statement for file containing the above PHP code */
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['myArray'] = [true, [3.14159, 'Bishop'], [null], 42];
        ___v();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Issues**

- Table is improperly formed if the first element is not an array (although doesn't happen in this case)
- No handling for `object` nor `resource` types, which I've yet to decide how to represent (suggestions welcome)

What I have so far seems to work fine, apart from the aforementioned issue, though the amount of code for what sounds like such a simple function is far above what I'd hoped, so I'd really appreciate any ideas on how to reduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://krumo.sourceforge.net/, maybe reinventing the wheel is not necessary :)

Even if you don't want to use it directly, reviewing the code might help you.